# asp.net paramter always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a problem with my asp.net app. This is my index.html

```html
@using BricksBreaking;
@model FieldModel



@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Game";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<table class="field">
    @for (int row = 0; row < Model.Field.RowCount; row++)
    {
        <tr>
            @for (int column = 0; column < Model.Field.ColumnCount; column++)
            {
                var tile = Model.Field.Tiles[row, column];

                if (tile == null)
                {
                    <td />
                }
                else
                {

                    if (Model.Field.Tiles[row, column].Color == TileColor.Red) {
                    <td>
                        <a href='/BricksBreaking/Click?r=@row?c=@column'>
                            <img src='/images/cervena.png' />
                        </a>
                        </td>
                    }if(Model.Field.Tiles[row, column].Color == TileColor.Yellow)
                    {
                    <td>
                        <a href='/BricksBreaking/Click?r=@row?c=@column'>
                            <img src='/images/zlta.png' />
                        </a>
                    </td>

                    }if(Model.Field.Tiles[row, column].Color == TileColor.Blue)
                    {
                    <td>
                        <a href='/BricksBreaking/Click?r=@row?c=@column'>
                            <img src='/images/modra.png' />
                        </a>
                    </td>

                    }
                }
            }
        </tr>
    }
        
</table>
```

And this is my controller

```html
    public class BricksBreakingController : Controller
    {
        ScoreServiceDatabase scoreService = new ScoreServiceDatabase();

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var field = new Field(9, 9, 5);
            HttpContext.Session.SetObject("field", field);
            var model = new FieldModel
            { Field = field, Scores = scoreService.GetTopScores() };
            return View(model);
        }

        public IActionResult Click(int r, int c)
        {
            var field = HttpContext.Session.GetObject("field") as Field;
            field.ClickTile(r,c);
            HttpContext.Session.SetObject("field", field);
            var model = new FieldModel
            { Field = field, Scores = scoreService.GetTopScores() };
            return View("Index", model);
        }


    }
}
```

Problem is. that always here at this line

```
<a href='/BricksBreaking/Click?r=@row?c=@column'>
```

Arguments passed to Function Click in controller are always 0. No matter if i write something like this

`<a href='/BricksBreaking/Click?r=2?c=2'>`

There will be always 0.

Can somebody help me with this? I am new to .NET.

Comment: Shouldn't that be ```/BricksBreaking/Click?r=2&c=2```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to write a `?` before the first parameter. Every parameter after the first needs a `&`

```
<a href='/BricksBreaking/Click?r=2&c=2'>
```

Comment: Yes , this helped. Thank you very much